# How to grant specific template friendship

Tags: c++, templates

```
template<typename T> void fun(const T&); // Lip 657

template<typename T> class Bar {
   // grants access to a single specific instance parametrized by char*

   friend void fun<char*> (char* const &); // case one
   friend void fun<char*> (const char* &); // case two
};
```

I assume the case one is the correct solution.

If any, why not case two instead of case one?

Comment: Umm. The difference between those 2 functions has nothing to do with templates or friendship.

Comment: @Falmarri, may you suggest a good title for this question?

Answer (score 2):

Template type arguments are like `typedef`.  Modifiers apply to the type as a whole, it does not act like string substitution.

So your supposition is correct.  `T` is a pointer, `fun` needs a reference to a `T` which is treated as `const`, the first version correctly describes reference to a pointer which is `const`.